# Pandas DataFrames - iteration format for itertuples

Tags: python, pandas

For all rows in a pandas DataFrame, I want to write rows to a new csv file where values for *both* columns 1 *and* 6 match the corresponding column values of all other rows, writing only the row with the largest value found in a different column (3). (Column 1 contains text and columns 3 and 6 contain integers.)

For example:

```
    0       1       2   3   4  5    6      
    0       spam        142         6
    1       eggs        212         3
    2       bacon       111         6
    3       eggs        128         3
    4       spam        221         6
    5       spam        144         4
    6       spam        145         6
```

In the above example, row 0 has column 1 and 6 values (spam, 6) that match those of rows 4 and 6 (both also have 'spam, 6'). Since row 4 has a higher column 3 value (221) than 0 (142) or 6 (145), I want to write row 4. Also, rows 1 and 3 match each other and row 1 has the higher column 3 value (212).

Desired output, part 1:

```
1       eggs        212         3
4       spam        221         6
```

Part 2... some of the rows will result in no match. In that case, I also want to write those rows (in the above example, rows 2 and 5 do not have any matches).

So considering these two parts, I want the output to write these rows:

```
1       eggs        212         3    
2       bacon       111         6
4       spam        221         6
5       spam        144         4
```

Here is what I think would be the most efficient process to do this:

- Write a new column (7) and add the integer 1 for row matches that
  do not have the highest column value.
- Then just print rows that
  are 'not 1' for column 7.

So, I need to iterate based on column 3, somehow identify those rows with values less than other matching values, write to a new column 7, and write the rows that do not have the value in column 7?

Is there a better process to do this? All I know is that I need to do some kind of iteration, mask, or column write, or some combination of the three. I have seen several questions here related to iterations, but none have helped me understand how to do it in this scenario. I am new to pandas, but guessing it starts with something like:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('pyall.csv')
for index, row in df.itertuples():
    mypairmatch = (index[2],index[7]) # stores two column values (1,6) of index
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be what you are looking for:

```
# Starting dataframe:
#    0      1   2    3   4   5  6
# 0  0   spam NaN  142 NaN NaN  6
# 1  1   eggs NaN  212 NaN NaN  3
# 2  2  bacon NaN  111 NaN NaN  6
# 3  3   eggs NaN  128 NaN NaN  3
# 4  4   spam NaN  221 NaN NaN  6
# 5  5   spam NaN  144 NaN NaN  4
# 6  6   spam NaN  145 NaN NaN  6

idx = df.groupby(['1', '6'])['3'].transform(max) == df['3']

df[idx]

#    0      1   2    3   4   5  6
# 1  1   eggs NaN  212 NaN NaN  3
# 2  2  bacon NaN  111 NaN NaN  6
# 4  4   spam NaN  221 NaN NaN  6
# 5  5   spam NaN  144 NaN NaN  4
```

**Explanation**

`df.groupby(['1', '6'])['3'].transform(max)` outputs a series giving the max values *groupwise* for each for each row, as so:

```
# 0    221
# 1    212
# 2    111
# 3    212
# 4    221
# 5    144
# 6    221
# Name: 3, dtype: int64
```

`df['3']` outputs just the series in column '3':

```
# 0    142
# 1    212
# 2    111
# 3    128
# 4    221
# 5    144
# 6    145
# Name: 3, dtype: int64
```

When these 2 series are compared for equality, you will only see `True` when both the index and values align:

```
# 0    False
# 1     True
# 2     True
# 3    False
# 4     True
# 5     True
# 6    False
# Name: 3, dtype: bool
```

Comment: There is output when running this with `print(idx)` of `0 False 1 True 2 False` etc. on my actual data, but what does that mean? I will run it with the sample data above and see if I can figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: This code correctly generates output of 'True' for having either 'no match' or having the highest column 3 value for matched rows.

Comment: @user3447273, I added an explanation - hope it helps.

Comment: It helped a lot. thanks. Can you help with a slight variation of the same problem? What if for some rows all three columns (1,3,6) were the same (there is no max value to select from) and you also wanted to write a row for only one of those? It could be the first available - it does not have to be random.